# Unusual behavior of find command

Tags: find

Please look at following out commands and their output:

```
$ cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size
  1920,1080
```

---

```
$ file /sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size
  /sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size: ASCII text
```

---

```
$ grep -H 1920 /sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size
  /sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size:1920,1080
```

so virtual_size is a normal text file

```
$ find /sys -type f -exec grep -H 1920 '{}' \; 2> /dev/null
  /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/blkio.throttle.io_service_bytes:8:0 Read 273361920
  /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/modes:1920x1080
  /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/graphics/fb0/modes:U:1920x1080p-0
  /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/graphics/fb0/virtual_size:1920,1080
  /sys/module/r8169/coresize:81920
```

but why find command fails to find `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size` file, it is just another text file right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size` **is** `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/graphics/fb0/virtual_size`.

Try `readlink -f /sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size` to confirm.

`namei -l /sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size` to see how that happened (one of the path components of `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size` at least must be a symbolic link).

`find` doesn't follow symbolic links when descending the directory tree unless you use the `-L` option (formerly `-follow` predicate).

However using it on `/sys` will get you nowhere as it's a spaghetti dish of symlinks.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds, `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size` itself is probably not a symlink, `/sys/class/graphics/fb0` may be.

Comment: yes the directory /fb0 is symlink

Comment: `file` command with `-L` option does not work as you said, please look at this [output](http://sprunge.us/DLjS)

Comment: @edwardtorvalds, `find`, not `file`. Try `find -L /sys` to see what I mean.